# unboundid ldap SDK how to get all users and exclude a department

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have sample code

```
Filter searchFilter = Filter.create("(sAMAccountType=805306368)");
                        SearchRequest searchRequest =
                                new SearchRequest(advanceBaseDnTxt.getText(), SearchScope.SUB, searchFilter,
                                        ldapAttributeSet);
                        SearchResult searchResult = lcon.search(searchRequest);
```

Is this enough **for retreiving all users** and how to exclude a department also?

Comment: `"(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(department=<NUMBER TO EXCLUDE>)))"` ?

Comment: @Esteban thank you. Also what is difference between (sAMAccountType=805306368) and (objectCategory=user))?

Comment: The same as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE accountType="foo"` and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowType="bar"` . It filters on 2 different attributes. From the attribute name I assume you use ActiveDirectory, and these attributes are specific of AD, this is not LDAP related. (And if by `objectCategory` you mean `objectClass`, it is a LDAP attribute which specifies the type of entry and its definition: which attributes are available for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate an attribute on a LDAP filter, look at this page : http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm

`(!(department=<NUMBER TO EXCLUDE>))` Should be used

If you need to filter on multiple attributes, from your example you need every entries which have `sAMAccountType=805306368` and are not in `department=<NUMBER TO EXCLUDE>`, so the filter will be :

`(&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!(department=<NUMBER TO EXCLUDE>)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer